# Can I get hplip 3.17.10 to work again in 17.10?

Tags: hp, 17.10

After upgrading 17.04 -> 17.10 I can no longer use hplip fully with my HP LaserJet Pro CM1415fmw (over network). I have removed and reinstalled 3.17.10 from HP but still several problems;

1) the hp-systray cannot find a place to put the tray icon (I guess GNOME doesn't support this). Even with "sleep 30" workaround described I get this error:

```
error:  No system tray detected on this system.  Unable to start, exiting.
```

Not a big issue - I can live with this.

2) I am no longer able to use hp-scan from the command line.

```
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

I see the printer in hp-toolbox and can print to it.

3) Running hp-toolbox and trying to install "Required Plugins" I get segmentation fault on the command line.

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work under 17.10?

Comment: About `hp-systray` here was a [bug 1714659](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1714659), but it seems to be fixed. I installed `hplip` from official repository. Icon is shown in GNOME Shell tray.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I cannot install the official hplip from repos, when trying to download the required plugin for my printer and scanner I get the following error: file does not match its checksum. File may have been corrupted or altered
I have reinstalled the official HPLIP from HP's site and can use the devices but no tray icon. Well, I guess HP will update their package soon.

Comment: You can try another Ubuntu mirror.

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/main/base/hplip

click on red button APT INSTALL,
when installation finished reboot

I tried it and it works!!

Answer (score 2):

hplip 3.7.11 supports Ubuntu 17.10 and all is now working as before. Installed from HP's official site and not through the repos.